# How can I prevent divs animated using CSS keyframes from colliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

How can I prevent a `div` whose `top` position is animated with CSS keyframes from colliding with another `div` which also is animated with the same keyframe in Javascript? I want to "pause" the keyframe, wait a little bit `(1s?)` and then restart it.
I've made a code to detect collision, but how can I pause the keyframe (cross browser) ? and then, how can I start it again?

**Keyframe:**

```
@keyframes moveItUp {
    10% {
        top: 18%;
    }
    20% {
        top: 16%;
    }
    30% {
        top: 14%;
    }
    40% {
        top: 12%;
    }
    50% {
        top: 10%;
    }
    60% {
        top: 8%;
    }
    70% {
        top: 6%;
    }
    80% {
        top: 4%;
    }
    90% {
        top: 2%;
    }
    100% {
        top: -20px;
    }
}
```

**Check collision of two div:**

```
jQuery.fn.collision = function($div2) {
    $div1  = $(this);
    var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
    var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
    var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
    var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
    var b1 = y1 + h1;
    var r1 = x1 + w1;
    var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
    var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
    var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
    var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
    var b2 = y2 + h2;
    var r2 = x2 + w2;

    if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
    return true;
};
```

Here's a demo of the collision code with the keyframe: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqVVqV

Comment: Can we see a demo of your code? It could help in suggesting a solution.

Comment: @Harry post edited

Comment: do you want something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/9x25dnfd/

Comment: @MrZ: Is [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/mPmmXx) what you need? The pause is for 2.5s upon collision (and I have moved the setInterval to be within the setTimeout because the collision check I think should be after the animation is added to the second element also and not before it).

Comment: @Harry thanks, working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to set the `animation-play-state` as `paused` when a collision is detected and then set it back again to `running` after the required amount of time (using a `setTimeout`).

The other thing that needs to be noted is that the collision check has to happen after both the elements get the animation added to them because otherwise there would be no animation to set the play-state for.  Alternately, we can also check if an animation is present on the element when collision is detected and set the `animation-play-state` to `paused` if there is an animation.

```js
jQuery.fn.collision = function($div2) {
  $div1 = $(this);
  var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
  var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
  var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
  var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
  var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
};

function tryCollision() {
  $('.test123').css('animation', 'moveItUp 10s');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.test321').css('animation', 'moveItUp 10s');
    var int = setInterval(function() {
      var res = $('.test321').collision($('.test123'));
      if (res == true) {
        $('body').append('<p>KEYFRAME for .test321 needs to be stopped and then continue after 1s</p>');
        
        /* set the animation's state to paused */
        $('.test321').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
        
        /* after the required amount of time set it back to running */
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.test321').css('animation-play-state', 'running')
        }, 2500);
        
        clearInterval(int);
      }
    }, 1);
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
@keyframes moveItUp {
  10% {
    top: 18%;
  }
  20% {
    top: 16%;
  }
  30% {
    top: 14%;
  }
  40% {
    top: 12%;
  }
  50% {
    top: 10%;
  }
  60% {
    top: 8%;
  }
  70% {
    top: 6%;
  }
  80% {
    top: 4%;
  }
  90% {
    top: 2%;
  }
  100% {
    top: -20px;
  }
}
.test123,
.test321 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 90%;
  left: 10px;
}
.test123 {
  background: #000;
}
.test321 {
  background: yellow;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test123">a</div>
<div class="test321">a</div>

<button onclick="tryCollision()">Try the collision</button>
```